# Does Apple reject the app if Bundle Display Name and iTunes app name are not identical?

Tags: app-store, itunes

Does Apple reject the app if Bundle Display Name and iTunes app name are not identical?

ex : My app name is ABC, iTunes doesn't let me use it in App Store as it's already taken by someone else. So, I'm going to change it as ABC - My country name.

Does it make a confusion to the user? And will my app get rejected by Apple?

Comment: Apparently, Bundle Display Name and iTunes app name should not be identical, but of course it should be somewhat similar to each other. So that the user knows it's the same app which is there in the App Store.
I got my previous version approved with app names in above format. Anyway having the same name is a good practice and which I'm going to follow in the next release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always maintain app names in iTunes Connect and as displayed on a device should be similar, so as not to cause confusion. Please refer 3.4 from apple review guide. [Apple Review Guide](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/2016-06-13/)